# How can I read from an already opened file in universal newline mode?

Tags: python, stream, newline

I have a file-like object representing a potentially endless stream. I want to read from this stream and count the lines, among other things, and I want to use universal newlines.

I don't have access to the statment that opens the file, so I can't just add `mode='rU'` to the open statement or equivalent thereof.

Nor can I read the entire file into memory and use `splitlines()` or `io.StringIO(unicode(mystream.read()), newline=None)`

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: "...potentially endless...count the lines" ∞

Comment: @Luigi I assume the OP means 'count the lines so far'

Comment: @aruisdante I figured but my brain threw a runtime error

Comment: close and reopen in `rU` mode

Comment: Yeah basically, count the lines so far. The line counting thread may not terminate though, it just publishes it's latest count for other threads to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python file-like object typically supports the ".fileno()" method. That returns the underlying file handle. Once you have the file handle, you should be able to use os.fdopen(file_handle, "rU") to obtain a new file object with universal newline semantics.